Debian 12 on an old packard bell EsyNote TJ65 how to make wireless work?
I recently took out an old Packard Bell Easynote TJ65.
Then I decided to install Debian 12 on it.
Everything during installation from CLI worked fine.
After install, it seems that the wireless card is not in use.
LSHW shows
*-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: AR928X Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
                vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                logical name: wlp3s0
                version: 01
                serial: 90:4c:e5:66:ea:33
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=6.1.0-25-686-pae firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.251 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:17 memory:f1200000-f120ffff

but it seems I can not manage that network card in any way. For example, I cannot change wireless connection. And if I unplug my cable, I can't ping anything despite what lshw prompts.
How can I make it work?

Try https://askubuntu.com/questions/220610/drivers-for-wifi-card-atheros-ar928x-find-and-install, https://askubuntu.com/questions/452826/wireless-networking-not-working-after-resume-in-ubuntu-14-04,

The solution was to go in /etc/network/interfaces and delete everything wireless related then reboot.
After that the NetworkManager.service decide to Manage the interface.
